# Adding textbox on button click with javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, onclick

I'm working on a web form with a textbox for pets and an "add pet" button. Each time the button is clicked, an additional textbox should be displayed below the original one.

I'm assuming this would be accomplished with an onclick event, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Project 4</title>
    </head>

    <body>
            <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            Pets: <input type="text" id="pets"> 
            <input type="button" id="addPet" value="Add Pet">
            <br>
            </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function makeCopy() {
                var copy = <input type="text">;
                return copy;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are other pieces to this as well, but none of them affect this particular problem I am having so didn't see the need to include the full code as it's fairly long.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Update:
I realize after reading the answers that I should've included more of my code to give you guys a better idea of the actual layout of my page. I have several text fields in my form and need the additional textboxes to be displayed right below the original "pets" textbox. Here's a jfiddle I threw together to give you guys a better idea of the layout. http://jsfiddle.net/a5m8nqwk/

Comment: Syntax error, `var copy = <input type="text">;` is bad JavaScript.

Comment: There are several complications on this problem. Namely, adding DOM elements, attaching event handlers, and setting new form element names to be unique and compatible with your server scripts. I'm just letting you know.

Comment: @Sukima, yeah, I mainly just put that in there so there would be something there. It showed the syntax error when I decided to try it just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily add elements to the DOM:

```
function createPetField() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.name = 'pet[]';
  return input;
}

var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
document.getElementById('addPet').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  form.appendChild(createPetField());
});
```

Comment: You had typo, `docent` :-)

Comment: This works, but I guess I should have posted more of my code. My actual page has several textboxes, and when I add this in, the additional boxes are positioned below the form. Is there a way to get the additional textboxes to display below the original one. I put together a fiddle to give you a better idea of the layout of my page. http://jsfiddle.net/a5m8nqwk/

Answer (score 3):

Something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/x7h96egn/)?

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    Pets: <br />
    <input type="text" id="pets" />
    <input type="button" id="addPet" value="Add Pet" />
    <br/>
</form>
```

```
document.getElementById("addPet").onclick = function() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    form.appendChild(input);
    form.appendChild(br);
}
```

**Edit**: I'd suggest using a table to style the input boxes, keep them in line. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5m8nqwk/1/)

Comment: Exactly, except that since I actually have several textboxes on my page, this is adding the additional textboxes below the form. Is there a way to to have the additional text fields display directly below the original. I'll put together a fiddle so you can get a better idea of the layout of my page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add(type) {

    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    var text = document.getElementById("textId");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    text.appendChild(element);

}
```

```css
 h1 {
            color: #0000ff;
        }
```

```html
<h1>KIAAT</h1>
    <b>Adding textbox on button click with javascript</b>
    <br><br>
<form>
    <input placeholder="text" name="element" hidden> </input>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>
    <span id="textId">&nbsp;</span>
</form>
```