# how do add dynamic textfield on button click

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I am working on jsp pages.Here i have requirements to add textfields on button click.

[image: as shown in image.]

I am unable to write java script function to add textField on button click.

```
 <body>
 <button type="button">Add more !</button>
 <table id="customers">
   <tr>
     <th>Product</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="product" value="product.."></input></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="quanty.."></input></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="price" value="price.."></input></td>
      </tr>
    // i want to add these fields dynamically on button click.
 </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you started with _JavaScript_ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding textbox on button click with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227487/adding-textbox-on-button-click-with-javascript)

Comment: @VinothKrishnan i had already tried this. but did,'t work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try. Just an example.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<button type="button">Add more !</button>
 <table id="customers">
   <tr>
     <th>Product</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="product" value="product.."></input></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="quanty.."></input></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="price" value="price.."></input></td>
      </tr>

 </table>

  <script>

     $(document).ready(function(){

       $("button").on("click", function(){

         var row = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="product" value="product.."></input></td><td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="quanty.."></input></td><td><input type="number" name="price" value="price.."></input></td></tr>';

         $("#customers").append(row);

       });

     });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Jenson M John it works fine in case of html . but not working in jsp.

Comment: `In case of HTML`?? What's the issue?? You can integrate JSP code within HTML

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example with pure js

```html
<p>Create Text Field.</p>

<button onclick="createFunction()">create it</button>

<script>
function createFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", "Hello Pritam !");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .clone() method to get a clone(copy) of the existing row. Then you can append() the new row.,

```
$("#add").click(function() {
  var table = $("#customers");
  table.append(table.find("tr:eq(1)").clone());

});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3936/)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how to add HTML in your page with jQuery.

```
$("BUTTON").click(function(){
    $("#customers TR").append('<td><input type="yourtype" name="yourname" value="yourvalue"></input></td>');
});
```

Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<table id="customers">
   <tr>
     <th>Product</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="product" value="product.."></input></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="quanty.."></input></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="price" value="price.."></input></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

jquery:

```
i = 1; // yoi can assign unique name to each textbox using this i
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#add").click(function() {
     $("#customers").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="product'+i+'" value="product.."></input></td> <td><input type="number" name="quantity'+i+'" value="quanty.."></input></td>     <td><input type="number" name="price'+i+'" value="price.."></input></td> </tr>');
     i++;

  })

});
```