# html text field from button event javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Wanting to create a button. Once button click onevent of the value.

```
<button type="button" value="xxxx">Press</button>
<button type="button" value="yyyy">Press</button>
```

value of xxx from button will enter the textfield with the value of the button as per value.

```
<input type="textarea" name="textfield" id="text">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227487/adding-textbox-on-button-click-with-javascript

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  It sounds like you're just looking for JavaScript tutorials at this point, and there are many available.

Comment: i have tried creating a script but the event is not working to putting the value into the textbox @Alexis

Comment: Share your script then

Comment: is the same as the suggested answers but not sure why is the textarea not capturing my input. im not sharing the my actual model. else u will be accusing me for being lazy. am just asking to clarify the concept @Alexis

Answer (score 0):

Define a function in Javascript

```
function fillText(value)
{
    document.getElementById('text').value = value;
}
```

And put that in the click event of button

```
<button type="button" value="xxxx" onclick="fillText(this.value)">Press</button>
<button type="button" value="yyyy" onclick="fillText(this.value)">Press</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

btn1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('text').value = e.target.value;
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('text').value = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn1" value="xxxx">Press</button>
<button id="btn2" value="yyyy">Press</button>

<input type="textarea" name="textfield" id="text">
```

Note : There is no need of `type=button` for `<button>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `document.GetElementById()` method.

First, create a JavaScript function:

```
function transfer(element) {
  document.getElementById("text").value = element.value;
}
```

Now, make the button run that function when it is pressed with itself as a parameter.

```
<button type="button" value="xxxx" onclick="transfer(this)">Press</button>
<button type="button" value="yyyy" onclick="transfer(this)">Press</button>
```